# Failed convert datetime,date,time using string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, datetime

I get an error about datetime,date and time.. i got 3 different datatype , mostly error all of them.. how do i get it right?

this datatype datetime: i dont know sometime i got it worked and some dont..

```
comu.Parameters.Add("Casedate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
comu.Parameters["Casedate"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text);
```

this are datatype date only:

```
comu.Parameters.Add("Startdate", SqlDbType.Date);
comu.Parameters["Startdate"].Value = Convert.ToString(TextBox12.Text);

comu.Parameters.Add("Enddate", SqlDbType.Date);
comu.Parameters["Enddate"].Value = Convert.ToString(TextBox13.Text);
```

this are datatype time:

```
comu.Parameters.Add("Starttime", SqlDbType.Time);
comu.Parameters["Starttime"].Value = Convert.ToString(TextBox14.Text);

comu.Parameters.Add("Endtime", SqlDbType.Time);
comu.Parameters["Endtime"].Value = Convert.ToString(TextBox15.Text);
```

now i have problem on datetime, but in the last page i got it worked by put in data 11/11/2014 data in it... but now it show error on datetime back

Comment: what is the format that user enters in `textbox`

Comment: for datetime should be dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

for time should be hh:mm:ss

for date should be dd/mm/yyyy

@SudhakarTillapudi

Answer (score 2):

if you know the DateTime format upfront you can use `DateTime.ParseExact()` method to parse the given date time value properly

```
using System.Globalization;

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(datestring, "dd/MM/yyyy 
                                  hh:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: im sorry , this are too advance for me.. idk how DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(datestring, "dd/MM/yyyy 
                                  hh:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); goes?

Comment: it parses the `DateTime` object from the given datetime  format exactly.please check this link for more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [DateTime.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, you are converting a string to a string.

```
DateTime.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
```